# How to enable routing in OS X El Capitan

Tags: macos, network, vmware

I've got a Linux VMware virtual machine (guest) configured with a NAT adapter on a 192.168.56.0 subnet. Its IP address is 192.168.56.128 and my Mac (host) got 192.168.56.1. Guest's default gateway is automatically set to 192.168.56.2 and is able to ping google from the guest. Host's Wi-Fi IP is 192.168.0.2,

I've configured my Wi-Fi router with following routing table to forward packets of 192.168.56.0 to 192.168.0.2 (my Mac)

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ route

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         172.16.4.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.16.4.0      *               255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.56.0    192.168.0.2     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.57.0    192.168.0.2     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlan0
```

But I'm unable to ping guest from any other device on the Wi-Fi network (192.168.0.0). So it's obvious that my Mac running OS X El Capitan is not forwarding the packets from 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.56.0

Answer (score 2):

Your router is not responsible to route packets from 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.56.0, but the VM host is. You have to keep the static route 192.168.56.0    -> 192.168.0.2 on the router though. I don't know what's the purpose of the second route 192.168.57.0 -> 192.168.0.2 - probably a second NAT adapter on the  host.

To reach your VM from **other** OS X devices in your 192.168.0.0 network you have to set up a static route on each of the 192.168.0.x machines to the VM host:

```
sudo route add -net 192.168.56.0  192.168.0.2
```

To make this route persistent add a launch daemon on each of the machines:

```
sudo nano /Library/LaunchDaemons/local.staticroute.vm.plist
```

with the content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>local.staticroute.vm</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>route</string>
      <string>add</string>
      <string>-net</string>
      <string>192.168.56.0</string>
      <string>192.168.0.2</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

save the file (ctrl-O) and quit nano (ctrl-X).

Load the launch daemon with:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/local.staticroute.vm.plist
```

---

If the other devices in the 192.168.0.0 network are Linux/Windows/Android hosts use the respective commands to add a route:

Windows (persistent):

```
route add -p 192.168.56.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.2
```

Linux:

```
route add -net 192.168.56.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.0.2
```

To add a persistent route in Linux check your Linux distro documentation.

Comment: what is this xml? This is the sickest use of XML i've ever come across!

Comment: This is to reach from other Macs on the network 192.168.0.0

Comment: I'm unable to reach my VM even from my router!

Comment: Yes my VM host is responsible for routing packets from `192.168.0.0` to `192.168.56.0`. So how to make the host(Mac) to do that?

Comment: @neckTwi Please implement my solution. Report back if you still have trouble. I tested it in a similar environment as yours and it works. **Please change the default gateway on the Linux VM to 192.168.56.1 (because this is the host's=gateway internal address).**

Comment: Yes I've implemented your solution. I've set default gw of vm to 192.168.56.1(MacHost). added static route to 192.168.56.0 via 192.168.0.2  on the router. and did `sudo route add -net 192.168.56.0  192.168.0.2` on the MacHost. I'm unable to ping the router from the VM.

Comment: @neckTwi You have to add the route (and/or the launch daemon) on every host in your 192.168.0.0 network except the VM host. And remove the route from the VM host with `sudo route delete -net 192.168.56.0 192.168.0.2` and any routing plist. The VM host **is** the router. It doesn't need an extra route! The VM host is your Mac! The VM is a host but it's not the **VM host**. The VM is a client on the VM host. You don't read my answer properly! And please don't mix/redefine common naming conventions!

Comment: I don't have any other device connected to the wifi except my Mac. All I want to do is ping the VM from the router. And VM can't even ping 192.168.0.2(Host WiFi IP)! Thank you for your effort to help.

Answer (score 0):

This didn't survive reboot for me in 10.11. I followed [these instructions](http://www.marcoach.nl/persistent-static-routes-on-os-x/):

```
sudo networksetup -setadditionalroutes Wi-Fi 192.168.56.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.2
```

where `Wi-Fi` is found using `networksetup -listallnetworkservices`.